# How to add scope to binding expressions in Delphi Live Bindings?

Tags: delphi, livebindings

I know how to use live bindings on a form to bind one property to another property using an expression.  For instance, binding a TLabel's Caption to a TEdit's text property.

I know how to create new expressions using IScope, TNestedScope, TDictionaryScope, etc.  I can add my own classes and call them as scripted expressions.

What I don't know is how to take my new expression scope and make it available to the TBindExpressions in my TBindingList for use on a form when I'm doing things described in the first paragraph.

Anyone know how to do this?  I've investigated, and I can't find a way to add an IScope reference to the binding expressions available to TBindingList and its sub-components.

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.Bind.Components.RegisterBindComponents  ???

Comment: David -- thanks for the response, but unless I am missing somthing, that isn't it.  I need to be able to register/add IScope instances, or at least it appears like that.

Comment: Do you know that is how it is done?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan -- Apparently not.  ;-)

Comment: I was not clear. I mean do you know for sure that adding an `IScope` is how to solve your problem?

Comment: No, I don't know that for sure.  IScope is what is produced when you add scripting classes to the existing scope, however, so that is my assumption.